# how to show only folders in jtree

Tags: java, file, jtree, explorer

I am currently this code for my JTree, but I want it only to show me the folders and not expand to show the files in every folder. Later I'm going to make my program show the files in another panel...

```
  package pm.entitymanager.presentation;

 import java.io.File;
 import java.util.Iterator;
 import java.util.Vector;
 import javax.swing.event.TreeModelEvent;
 import javax.swing.event.TreeModelListener;
 import javax.swing.tree.TreeModel;
 import javax.swing.tree.TreePath;

 /**
  *
  * @author Volpym
  */
public class FileSystemModel implements TreeModel {

private File root;
private Vector listeners = new Vector();

public FileSystemModel(File rootDirectory) {
    root = rootDirectory;
}

@Override
public Object getRoot() {
    return root;
}

@Override
public Object getChild(Object parent, int index) {
    File directory = (File) parent;
    String[] children = directory.list();
 /*       for (int j = 0; j< children.length; j++ ){
        System.out.println(children[j]);
    }       */

    return new FileSystemModel.TreeFile(directory, children[index]);
}

@Override
public int getChildCount(Object parent) {
    File file = (File) parent;
    if (file.isDirectory()) {
        String[] fileList = file.list();

        if (fileList != null) {
            return file.list().length;
        }
    }

}

@Override
public boolean isLeaf(Object node) {
    File file = (File) node;
    return file.isFile();
}

@Override
public int getIndexOfChild(Object parent, Object child) {
    File directory = (File) parent;
    File file = (File) child;
    String[] children = directory.list();
    for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        if (file.getName().equals(children[i])) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;

}

@Override
public void valueForPathChanged(TreePath path, Object value) {
    File oldFile = (File) path.getLastPathComponent();
    String fileParentPath = oldFile.getParent();
    String newFileName = (String) value;
    File targetFile = new File(fileParentPath, newFileName);
    oldFile.renameTo(targetFile);
    File parent = new File(fileParentPath);
    int[] changedChildrenIndices = {getIndexOfChild(parent, targetFile)};
    Object[] changedChildren = {targetFile};
    fileTreeNodesChanged(path.getParentPath(), changedChildrenIndices, changedChildren);

}

private void fileTreeNodesChanged(TreePath parentPath, int[] indices, Object[] children) {
    TreeModelEvent event = new TreeModelEvent(this, parentPath, indices, children);
    Iterator iterator = listeners.iterator();
    TreeModelListener listener = null;
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        listener = (TreeModelListener) iterator.next();
        listener.treeNodesChanged(event);
    }
}

@Override
public void addTreeModelListener(TreeModelListener listener) {
    listeners.add(listener);
}

@Override
public void removeTreeModelListener(TreeModelListener listener) {
    listeners.remove(listener);
}

private class TreeFile extends File {

    public TreeFile(File parent, String child) {
        super(parent, child);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getName();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I used the code provided by @ug_ I was still getting the files, after searching the net i came up with this lines of code and they work.

```
    FilenameFilter directoryFilter = new FilenameFilter() {
@Override
public boolean accept(File file, String name) {

     return new File(file, name).isDirectory();
}
```

Comment: Good call, overlook on my part. You should accept your awnser.